# Java: don't understand this 'while' condition

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a method that accepts an input number and compares it to the number in an integer array and returns true or false depending if the value is found. The method works fine but I am having trouble interpreting a line of code within. Specifically at the `while` statement `(!found && index < accounts.length)`. The way my brain interprets this is as "while found is not false AND index is smaller than the length of the accounts array"... but I do not understand how the `!found` part can be compared with a `<` operator. The complete method is below.

```
public static boolean account(int input) {
    // account array
    int accounts[] = { 5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 4581002 };

    // Loop control variable
    int index = 0;

    // Search results
    boolean found = false;

    // Search the array.
    while (!found && index < accounts.length) {
        if (accounts[index] == input) {
            found = true;
        }
        // Increment index
        index++;
    }

    // Return result of search
    return found;

}
```

Comment: You can return `true` as soon  as you have matched the element.  The `found` variable is not even needed.

Comment: @theProgrammer101 Technically speaking `while` is a keyword and a statement.

Comment: @EJP would you call while a conditional statement?

Answer (score 1):

> The way my brain interprets this is as "while found is not false AND index is smaller than the length of the accounts array"

Your brain should interpret it as "while found is not ***true*** AND index is smaller than the length of the accounts array".

The while loop ends when either all the elements of `accounts` has been searched or the matching account has been found.

Comment: part 1 is incorrect, found holds the value of false

Answer (score 1):

The `<` does not apply to `!found`, it only applies to `index` and `accounts.length()`. `!found` and `index < accounts.length` are two different, separate conditions. Both must be true for the loop to run. You could write that line like so, if it helps you understand.

```
 while ((!found) && (index < accounts.length)) {
```

This line is saying 2 things:

1. while found is not true (`found` *would* hold the value of true, but it is negated by `!`)

and

2. `index` is less than `accounts.length` (however many members are in the `accounts` array)

then it will execute whatever is in the controlled block inside the braces.

Comment: @EddyZavala I hope this is clear to you, I did my best to break it down, and make my answer as simple as possible, while still explaining the issue completely

Comment: please comment below if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

Your method looks for `int input` in `accounts` array. If the same value as `input` is found while loop breaks and method returns true.

while statement says: loop until `found` is false and `index` is less than `accounts.length`.

Answer (score 0):

`!found` refers to a boolean value, set to `false`.

So, in the parentheses, we have "not false AND index less than length of accounts array",

which is equivalent to "true AND index less than length of accounts array".

Index is set to a value, eg. 0 at the start. Let's say length of accounts array is 5. Then we have "0 is less than 5". This statement is mathematically true, and so evaluates to the boolean true.

Then, our statement has simplified to "true AND true", which is logically true. In the context of the while loop, we have `while (true)`, which as such will execute the while loop.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need further clarification!

Answer (score 0):

> but I do not understand how the !found part can be compared with a < sign.

Since the precedence of ! operator is more than &&  operator,the value of found is negated first and then value of index and length of accounts array is compared with < operator .Consider it  like this:

```
(!found) && (index < accounts.length)
```